# NoMethodError (undefined method `validate' for true:TrueClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

This specific line in my model

```
validates :password, 
     length: { minimum: 8 }, 
     allow_nil: true, 
     on: :create, 
     unless: (:uid.present? && :provider.present?)
```

is causing

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `validate' for true:TrueClass)
```

and no errors during update_user.

**Is there any syntax mistake?** maybe something like the arguments are not sent properly or is it something else?

Comment: I do have `has_secure_password` that it generates `password_digest` removing `password` field, has this got anything to do with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is occuring becuase of

```
unless: (:uid.present? && :provider.present?)
```

so replace it with

```
unless: Proc.new{|u| u.uid.present? && u.provider.present?}
```

and it will work.

Let me know if you are still facing the issue.

Comment: boom it works! i think it used to work before _(not sure though)_. but why how?

Comment: Wow. It worked. Can somebody explain what is a "Proc"

Answer (score 4):

The `unless` option for `validates` requires a Symbol or a Proc.

```
validates :password, 
  length: { minimum: 8 }, 
  allow_nil: true, 
  on: :create, 
  unless: Proc.new{ |model_instance| model_instance.uid.present? && model_instance.provider.present?}
```

The Proc syntax isn't the most readable thing in the world, so if you wanted to clean this up a bit you'd pass a Symbol to the `unless` option and define an instance method with the same name.

```
class User
  include ActiveModel::Model

  validates :password, 
    length: { minimum: 8 }, 
    allow_nil: true, 
    on: :create, 
    unless: :has_uid_and_provider?

  def has_uid_and_provider?
    uid.present? && provider.present?
  end
end
```

Comment: so if `unless` had just `uid.present?` rails would create `Proc.new{|u| u.uid.present?}` ...?

Comment: I simply thought `unless` needs to be provided with a `Boolean`, so assigning any expression that evaluates to a `Boolean` or even providing a func that would return a `Boolean` would indeed work, shouldn't it be working like this? Why? Why not?

Comment: You're on the right path, but the trick here is the scope.  `validates` is a Class method - but the validation is applied to an instance of the model.  Rails bridges that gap by providing the method name (Symbol) or an inline Proc.  Notice how the Proc yields the model instance thats being validated!

Comment: oh, that's fine, but why is it not reporting `can't find uid of undefined` sorta error _that should arise due to scope_, when it has a simple `Bool` check _(only `uid.present?`)_